# How to return a MySQL procedure as a trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, plpgsql, procedure

I'm new to MySQL procedures. I need to emulate some code that I usually do with PLpgSQL, something like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS "aprtr_controlo_tabelas_ins_upd" () CASCADE;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "aprtr_controlo_tabelas_ins_upd" ()         
RETURNS trigger AS

$BODY$
        BEGIN
            IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                NEW.data_ult_actual := current_timestamp;
                NEW.id_utiliz_ins := current_user;
            RETURN NEW;
            ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                NEW.data_ult_actual := current_timestamp;
                NEW.id_utiliz_upd := current_user;
            RETURN NEW;
            END IF;

            RETURN NULL;
        END;
$BODY$
        LANGUAGE PLpgSQL
        CALLED ON NULL INPUT
        VOLATILE
        EXTERNAL SECURITY DEFINER;
```

It is possible in MySQL to write procedures that return a trigger? Or better, can I use a procedure code and call it trigger in an operation of INSERT or UPDATE?

Best Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "procedures that return a trigger"? A trigger is attached to a specific table, and is executed when some data gets inserted/updated/deleted. You may use a procedure to define a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL only supports specific data types as function return types. As per MySQL documentation `trigger` is not a data type. Custom objects as data types is not a feature AFAIK. Supported data types are detailed [***here***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-overview.html).

Referene: [***MySQL CREATE FUNCTION Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html).