# Using Info From Other Tables in 'With Recursive'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few tables for:

- products (that have one or multiple categories)
- shelves (that are meant for certain parent/super_categories)
- a planogram for placing a certain product on a shelf

I've been trying to create a function that, given a planogram, raises an error if none of the product's categories belong to the shelf's hierarchy of categories, but I'm having some trouble with the multiple 'WITH's, and keep getting hit with syntax errors at or near the recursive with. What could I do better?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chk_insert_planogram()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    WITH cat_id AS (
        SELECT category_name
        FROM shelf
        WHERE ivm_manuf = NEW.ivm_manuf
        AND ivm_serial_number = NEW.ivm_serial_number
        AND shelf_nr = NEW.shelf_nr
    )
    , product_categories AS (
        SELECT category_name
        FROM has_category
        WHERE product_ean = NEW.product_ean
    )
    , RECURSIVE shelf_categories(child_category,super_category) AS (
    SELECT child_category,super_category
        FROM has_other 
        WHERE super_category IN cat_id
        UNION ALL
    SELECT others.child_category, others.super_category
        FROM has_other others
        INNER JOIN shelf_categories
        ON others.super_category = shelf_categories.child_category
    )
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT category_name 
        FROM product_categories
        WHERE category_name IN cat_id
        OR category_name IN (
            SELECT child_category
            FROM shelf_categories
        )
    )
    THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Products categories not present in selected shelf';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(The cat_id is unique but I think because we're working with tables I have to use "IN cat_id" instead of "=cat_id", right?)

The relevant tables are:

```
create table planogram (
    product_ean char(13) not null,
    shelf_nr numeric(16,0) not null,
    ivm_serial_number numeric(5,0) not null,
    ivm_manuf varchar(255) not null,
    faces_seen numeric(16, 0) not null,
    units numeric(3, 0) not null,
    loc numeric(3, 0) not null,
    constraint pk_planogram primary key(product_ean, shelf_nr, ivm_serial_number, ivm_manuf),
    constraint fk_planogram_product foreign key(product_ean) references product(product_ean),
    constraint fk_planogram_shelf foreign key(shelf_nr, ivm_serial_number, ivm_manuf) references shelf(shelf_nr, ivm_serial_number, ivm_manuf)
);

create table shelf (
    shelf_nr numeric(16,0) not null,
    ivm_serial_number numeric(5,0) not null,
    ivm_manuf varchar(255) not null,
    shelf_height numeric(5, 2) not null,
    category_name varchar(255) not null,
    constraint pk_shelf primary key(shelf_nr, ivm_serial_number, ivm_manuf),
    constraint fk_shelf_ivm foreign key(ivm_serial_number, ivm_manuf) references ivm(ivm_serial_number, ivm_manuf),
    constraint fk_shelf_category foreign key(category_name) references category(category_name)
);

create table super_category (
    category_name varchar(255) not null,
    constraint pk_super_category primary key(category_name),
    constraint fk_super_category_category foreign key(category_name) references category(category_name)
);

create table has_other (
    super_category varchar(255) not null,
    child_category varchar(255) not null,
    constraint pk_has_other primary key(child_category),
    constraint fk_has_other_super_category foreign key(super_category) references super_category(category_name),
    constraint fk_has_other_category foreign key(child_category) references category(category_name)
);

create table has_category (
    product_ean char(13) not null,
    category_name varchar(255) not null,
    constraint pk_has_category primary key(product_ean, category_name),
    constraint fk_has_category_product foreign key(product_ean) references product(product_ean),
    constraint fk_has_category_category foreign key(category_name) references category(category_name)
);
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  `WITH` clause is new in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2.2.  Also, show the exact error, plus all the required tables used in that SQL.  Some are missing.  Test the query outside the procedure.  RECURSIVE is an optional keyword that is found directly after the `WITH` keyword.  Your `IF` **statement** doesn't appear to be valid.

Comment: Suggestion: Build your SQL one `WITH` clause term at a time.  Don't add the next `WITH` clause term until the prior is known to be valid.

Comment: Is this intended to be a function or a trigger? Triggers usually follow `CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name`.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898963/2067753 So if wanting a function where are you comparing any of the category data to a "selected shelf"? There does not appear to be a parameter or comparison to a specific  planogram.

Comment: PG supports functions returning triggers. But the tag is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me if you need a function or a trigger, but to start, I suggest you first develop a viable select query to verify if your recursive logic is sound. e.g.

```
SET @ivm_manuf = '1';
SET @ivm_serial_number = '2';
SET @shelf_nr = '3';

/* start using "with recursive" */
WITH RECURSIVE shelf_categories (lvl, child_category, super_category)
        AS (
        SELECT
              1 as lvl
            , child_category
            , super_category
        FROM has_other
        WHERE super_category IN (
                SELECT category_name
                FROM shelf
                WHERE ivm_manuf = @ivm_manuf
                    AND ivm_serial_number = @ivm_serial_number
                    AND shelf_nr = @shelf_nr
                )
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT
              lvl + 1 as lvl
            , has_other.child_category
            , has_other.super_category
        FROM shelf_categories
        INNER JOIN has_other ON shelf_categories.child_category = has_other.super_category
        WHERE lvl < 20 /* include some way to "escape" from the recursion */
        )
SELECT *
FROM shelf_categories
```

1. change the parameter data types and values to suit your data
2. commence the with clause using `with recursive` even if the first CTE you define does not require recursion see [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d21e063646a78a7fcd349988174f3c3e) for examples of this.
3. In the recursive CTE, in the second select, use the name of that cte in the from clause joining to other tables as needed
4. include a way to escape from the recursion
5. Once the select query is operating successfully convert it to either a trigger or function